# Laravel user get relation tables

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-5, sentinel

To get all the user informations in laravel 5.2 I use the Sentinel user system.

I can recive with $request->user() all the informations from the 'users' table. But i want get also every row from the 'messages' table.

I create a relation between 'users'.'ID' and 'messages'.'UID' but in Laravel the $request->user() content is still the same.

What do i need to modify to get all relation columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eager load the relations you can use the following method:

```
$user = $request->user();
$user->load('messages');
```

For that, in User Model, you need to define the relationship:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```